No Game Piece movement in simple 2x2 board game MVP in Unity3D
I am trying to make a board game in Unity3D. I have already published 2 apps and this is my next project. I would like to make a basic test of what I am trying to do by developing a board game with simple four tiles (2x2). On one tile will sit a sphere (our game piece) and this will be able to be selected and then moved around the board. I did research and found that it seems you have to log your transforms in an array and then move through that array's indexes. I attempted the code below and the game piece still does not move when I click on it.
public class GameRun : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject selectedPiecePrefab; // Drag & drop the game piece prefab here in the inspector

    public Transform[] boardSpaces; // Array of Transforms representing the movement locations

    private GameObject selectedPiece;
    private int selectedPieceIndex = -1; // Track selected piece index
    private Vector3 moveDirection; // Store movement direction based on clicks
    private float moveSpeed = 5.0f;

    private Animation anim;
    public Animator m_Animator;

    void Start()
    {
        // Ensure assign all board spaces in the inspector
        if (boardSpaces.Length != 4)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Please assign all four board spaces in the inspector for GameManager!");
        }
        m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Handle selection and deselection based on clicks
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Transform hitTransform = hit.transform;

                // Deselect if clicked outside the game piece
                if (selectedPiece != null && hitTransform.gameObject != selectedPiece)
                {
                    DeselectPiece();
                }

                // Select a game piece on click (assuming GamePiece script attached)
                if (hitTransform.GetComponent<GamePiece>() != null)
                {
                    SelectPiece(hitTransform.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }

        // Move the selected piece on second click (if a piece is selected)
        if (selectedPiece != null && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                // Check if clicked on a board space
                if (boardSpaces.Contains(hit.transform))
                {
                    int targetIndex = Array.IndexOf(boardSpaces, hit.transform);
                    if (IsValidMove(targetIndex))
                    {
                        moveDirection = hit.point - selectedPiece.transform.position;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Apply movement smoothly based on moveDirection
        if (selectedPiece != null && moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            Vector3 targetPosition = selectedPiece.transform.position + moveDirection;
            selectedPiece.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(selectedPiece.transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Deselect on right-click
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            DeselectPiece();
        }
    }

    void SelectPiece(GameObject piece)
    {
        selectedPiece = piece;
        selectedPieceIndex = -1; // Reset index when selecting a new piece

        // Acknowledge selection (e.g., print message)
        Debug.Log("Selected game piece: " + piece.name);

        // Call selection function on GamePiece script (if implemented)
        piece.GetComponent<GamePiece>()?.Select();

        anim.Play("Forward");
        m_Animator.SetBool("thisWay", true);
    }

    void DeselectPiece()
    {
        selectedPiece = null;
        selectedPieceIndex = -1;

        // Consider: Call visual deselection function on GamePiece script
        if (selectedPiece != null)
        {
            selectedPiece.GetComponent<GamePiece>()?.Deselect();
        }

    }

    bool IsValidMove(int newIndex)
    {
        // Check if the new index is within board bounds and has an empty space
        return newIndex >= 0 && newIndex < boardSpaces.Length && boardSpaces[newIndex] == null;
    }
}

I have tried implementing a new set of code entirely and instead only resulted with erratic movement with the WASD keys where the game piece still did not move between the actual transforms:
public class BoardMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float tileSize = 1.0f; // The size of each tile on the board
    private int selectedPieceIndex = 0; // The index of the selected piece
    public GameObject selectedPiece; // Reference to the selected game piece

    // Array to store the transforms of each tile
    public Transform[] tileTransforms = new Transform[4];

    public float moveSpeed = 5.0f; // Adjust this value for desired speed

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize the tile transforms based on their positions
        for (int i = 0; i < tileTransforms.Length; i++)
        {
            tileTransforms[i].position = IndexToWorldPosition(i);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Move up (W key)
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && IsValidMove(selectedPieceIndex - 2))
        {
            selectedPieceIndex -= 2;
            MovePiece(selectedPieceIndex);
        }

        // Move down (S key)
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && IsValidMove(selectedPieceIndex + 2))
        {
            selectedPieceIndex += 2;
            MovePiece(selectedPieceIndex);
        }

        // Move left (A key)
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && IsValidMove(selectedPieceIndex - 1))
        {
            selectedPieceIndex -= 1;
            MovePiece(selectedPieceIndex);
        }

        // Move right (D key)
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && IsValidMove(selectedPieceIndex + 1))
        {
            selectedPieceIndex += 1;
            MovePiece(selectedPieceIndex);
        }
    }

    void MovePiece(int newIndex)
    {
        // Check if newIndex is valid
        if (newIndex >= 0 && newIndex <= 3)
        {
            Vector3 targetPosition = tileTransforms[newIndex].position;
            Debug.Log("Moving to: " + targetPosition); // Check the target position
            selectedPiece.transform.position = targetPosition;
        }
    }

    // Method to check if the move is valid
    bool IsValidMove(int newIndex)
    {
        // Check if the new index is within the bounds of the 2x2 board
        return newIndex >= 0 && newIndex <= 3;
    }

    // Method to convert board index to world position
    Vector3 IndexToWorldPosition(int index)
    {
        float x = (index % 2) * tileSize;
        float z = (index / 2) * tileSize;
        return new Vector3(x, 0, z);
    }
}

Neither script is able to achieve a moving game piece, even when I tried to ignoring the more complete selection process and go right for the WASD key clicking. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? How do I create a script to achieve my 2x2 board game MVP?
